# RabbitMQ: In case of a Master queue going down , Is there a way to get those messages which are not replicated to mirror queues?

Tags: rabbitmq

When the master node comes up and we make it the mirror of newly elected master.

Is there a configuration or way to re-queue those messages which were not replicated to mirror at the time of master going down ?.

I don't want to lose those messages. I am using ack=1 as I don't want to compromise on producer latency. I am okay with delayed delivery of the un-replicated messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [`automatic` in `ha-sync-mode`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) for ex:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "" '{"ha-mode":"all", ,"ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
```

Comment: I didn't understand, using `"ha-sync-mode":"automatic"` the messages are mirrored automatically. In which way you lose messages ?

Comment: I don't want to use automatic mode. my call will return after writing successfully to master. I can loose messages if master goes down and some messages are not mirrored. This is what i have edited in the question